# Simple file share failover

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, high-availability, file-server

I have a simple file share on Windows 2012 R2 server which I would like to be high available. I created failover cluster, but I'm not able to set up FileServer service as there is no shared storage. For my purposes buying high available shared storage is very expensive option.

The manual way would be to create secondary file share and use `robocopy` for syncing. In case of failover I would need to change network path to 2nd server.

Is there any fully-automated solution which is free or included in Windows licence?

Comment: Maybe [DFSR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and skip robocopy completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use DFS and setup replication between the servers, you can set it for one way or full mesh replication.  [DFS Blog from MS.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2013/08/20/dfs-replication-in-windows-server-2012-r2-if-you-only-knew-the-power-of-the-dark-shell.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me to the right direction. It seems that DFS Replication can be used without Failover Cluster. It can't be set up becuase of Win2003 domain controller. Until upgraded I will use robocopy for sync, high availability should work already.